# Are there good ways to find a row that has sum of difference over threshold between another row with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find a row that has sum of difference over threshold between another row with postgresql.

For example with the script below, I can create test table.

```
/*prepare for test table*/
with recursive target_table(time,target,value,flg) as(
    select
        1
        , random()
        , random()
        , false
    union all
    select
        time+1
        , random()
        , random()
        , case when time=9 then true else false end
    from target_table
    where time < 20
)
select *,sum(value) over (order by time) as sum_of_value from target_table;
```

And table below is a sample table.

```
1   0.5955741602068017  0.062468466592012106    false   0.062468466592012106
2   0.9599096994358831  0.2721417844426348  false   0.3346102510346469
3   0.5219622680617206  0.47568365271884616 false   0.8102939037534931
4   0.19330178068888415 0.055219926055169566    false   0.8655138298086626
5   0.7849454445680166  0.869388793530252   false   1.7349026233389147
6   0.3818554639492504  0.6618063662299782  false   2.396708989568893
7   0.14781479428049948 0.2939156384156725  false   2.6906246279845654
8   0.35489557675010985 0.3223190750002196  false   3.012943702984785
9   0.7468542842938106  0.4682370283799777  false   3.4811807313647627
10  0.9827402637131684  0.8947818572002681  false   4.375962588565031
11  0.9795760087001852  0.7735269168553209  false   5.149489505420352
12  0.7201651414850829  0.9190766910614023  false   6.068566196481754
13  0.4675524690241204  0.5993146022105726  false   6.667880798692327
14  0.7946650321278526  0.3035202408540094  false   6.971401039546336
15  0.9985454346140514  0.5523127942270101  true    7.523713833773346
16  0.5638512819364934  0.5059578895998662  false   8.029671723373212
17  0.3087199667465299  0.7731866673265166  false   8.802858390699729
18  0.5435603740732802  0.34633746722375847 false   9.149195857923488
19  0.9042064638800369  0.8654612596373745  false   10.014657117560862
20  0.6421889049801024  0.6367246358906549  false   10.651381753451517
```

I would like to find a closest row that has sum of difference over threshold between the 15th row that flag is true.

In this time if the threshold is 5, I would like to find the row that has sum of difference over 5 with 15th row. And that is 6th row. Because 7.523713833773346-2.396708989568893=5.1270048442 is over 5 and that is closest from 15th.

And of course there tremendous volume of data in the table in fact.
How can I find the every row that suit the row with flag true?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select max(t.id)
from mytable t
inner join mytable t15 
    on  t15.id = 15
    and t15.sum_of_value - t.sum_of_value > 5
```

This gives you the greatest id of records whose value has a difference greater than 5 with the value of record that has id 15.

If you want the whole record, then:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join mytable t15 
    on  t15.id = 15
    and t15.sum_of_value - t.sum_of_value > 5
order by t1.id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay!
I am inspired with your join strategy.
And now I can do what I want!